# Access IP Tables in Azure Container Instances

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I am trying to use this OpenVPN image in ACI (https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn).  As part of it, it tries to set iptables and fails.

`+ setupIptablesAndRouting
+ iptables -t nat -C POSTROUTING -s 192.168.255.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables v1.6.2: can't initialize iptables table 'nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
+ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.255.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables v1.6.2: can't initialize iptables table 'nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`

It is likely because the docker image uses `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` for normal running in Docker.  Is there a way to do this in ACI (or run that iptables command with higher permissions)?

Comment: Why do you want to set up iptables in the container? It seems you do not have the permission to execute the command.

Comment: OpenVPN requires setting iptables to forward traffic.  It appears this is not possible today as someone replied on twitter: https://twitter.com/yangl900/status/1039262974936985600